# Objective C - Replacing portion of string in NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, replace

I am using the following code to replace a portion of the string, this works for normal characters (alphabetical characters) but when it comes to symbols like "•" it can't replace the character.

Any solution?

```
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"•" withString:@"<BULLET_POINT>"];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may not be able to literally insert non-ASCII characters like "•" in a source file. Try using the escape `\u2022` instead.

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2022" withString:@"<BULLET_POINT>"];
```

Comment: It seems like the method "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" return a new string with the replacement and it doesn't actually modify the current string

Comment: @aryaxt: that's right, and is because NSString is an immutable object. If you have an NSMutableString you can use `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` instead of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString...`.